# [HY000][100022] [Vertica][VJDBC](100022) Unknown message type: v

Tags: vertica, datagrip

I get this error when I try to connect to a Vertica with DataGrip:

```
DBMS: 
Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=exact
Driver:  (ver. , JDBC)
Effective version: Vertica (ver. 0.0)
[HY000][100022] [Vertica][VJDBC](100022) Unknown message type: v.
```

[Parameters that I enter when connecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPpAr.png)

Comment: Have you added the Vertica JDBC driver , for example, vertica-jdbc-11.0.2-4.jar, as a custom JAR? look at this link:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/configuring-database-connections.html#configure-driver-from-the-existing-procedure

Comment: I have already tried to load custom drivers using JAR file, but it gives the same error (tried version 9.2.0, 9.1.1, 12.0.1)

Comment: If this issue has not been resolved yet, please report it here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

and provide idea log from Help - Show Log in Files. We'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you mistakenly attempted to connect to a PostgreSQL instance instead of Vertica. By default they listen on very similar port numbers; Vertica on 5433 and PostgreSQL on 5432. [Vertica's wire format](https://integrators.vertica.com/data-protocols-formats/frontend-backend/), which inherits from an earlier PostgreSQL version, doesn't have message type 'v' within it, but [PostgreSQL does have message type 'v'](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-message-formats.html), meaning NegotiateProtocolVersion. Hence, the PostgreSQL server sending message type 'v' and the Vertica JDBC driver not understanding it.